# Getting relative time to destination on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

On Google maps you can input a user's *current position* and *destination*, and you then get a relative time to the destination either by car or by walking. Is it possible to get said time to destination *without* accessing the map? I want to store the time to destination in an integer variable.

Are there any tutorials or examples on this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)